# prestashop 1.7.2.0: how to edit footer ("Contact information" module)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to edit the content in the footer (under "store information"):

I believe it's stored in the "Contact information" module. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to edit its content.

Please help!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default PS 1.7 displays several modules in the footer, one of which is `ps_contactinfo`.

You can override the template files ( `ps_contactinfo.tpl` is the one for the footer ) by creating a `ps_contactinfo` directory in `themes/[YOUR_THEME]/modules` and start by copy pasting the `ps_contactinfo.tpl` file from the base module and work from there.

p.s.: your site is password locked so i couldn't see for sure what is in your footer

Comment: oh, didn't realize that, thanks. Actually I'm just looking to edit the content of the footer (ie: translate the "email us" wording), no need to change the layout. I posted a screenshot, does that help? Thanks =)

Comment: Oh, you should be able to just translate the "email us" string via the modules translations in `International > translations` and thens elect "module translations" and try editing the "Contact Information" module

Answer (score 0):

No need to edit the code. you can edit it from the shop itself.
Go to shop parameter > contacts > stores.

Comment: Kindly use Comments section for Comments.

Comment: This was my answer. is it ok for an answer?